# Getting error in riverpod statement in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I have started learning flutter with a channel guide,

In the first lesson I am getting an error,

I am getting an error in the following line

```
final number=watch(provider);
```

and here is full code

```
final provider=Provider<int>((ref)=>20);

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('RiverPod'),),
      body: Center(child: Consumer(
          builder: (context,watch,child){
            final number=watch(provider);
//getting an error in above statement, red line under watch(provider)
            return Text(number.toString());

          },
          child: Text('Riverpod')),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That might be old code, where ref.watch was passed down directly as the second arg.  Modern riverpod uses ref there instead, so you have to then say ref.watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the builder is defined something like

```dart
 builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
```

So the second one provide `WidgetRef` and you can get `.watch` from this ref.

You can refactor like this to avoid misconception

```dart
builder: (context, ref, child) {
  final number = ref.watch(provider);
```